# Rust Polars convert DataFrame into tuples

Tags: rust-polars

I use this code to convert a DF into tuples:

```
    // Combine vectors into a new vector of tuples
    let combined_data: Vec<(i64, i32, f64, f64)> =
        timestamp
            .into_iter()
            .zip(side.into_iter())
            .zip(size.into_iter())
            .zip(price.into_iter())
            .map(|(((ts, s), sz), pr)| (ts, s, sz, pr))
            .collect();
```

I also made a version for 12 columns. Any one could suggest a way to convert in a general way for any numbers of columns?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`izip!`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.izip.html) from `itertools`, which “splats” the tuple for you.

```rust
izip!(timestamp, side, size, price).collect::<Vec<_>>() // Vec of 4-tuples
```

Note that even in your example, you only need `into_iter()` on `timestamp`; the `zip` method only requires that its argument be `IntoIterator`, not `Iterator`.

Comment: This way makes it simple, maybe I could try to make a general version myself and share.